# C++ - Optimal way to use multiple values as a key in unordered_map

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map, stdtuple, state-space

I'm programming the class for working with state-spaces. My problem is, that I don't know, what's the ideal way to use multiple values as a key in `unordered_map`.

---

It's supposed to work this way:

I create the state object with values <1;0;8>, so it'll be inserted into the hashmap as `<1;0;8>:pointer_to_object`. I want the hashmap because I need to find
objects as fast as possible.

---

I thought about using [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or [tuple](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/).

Is it possible to use one of them as a key for `unordered_map` without specifying their size in advance?

---

#### EDIT:

I've tried to use the code recommended by @the_mandrill like this:

```
template <class T>
typedef std::unordered_map<std::vector<T>, State<T>*, boost::hash<std::vector<T>> Map;

template <class T>
size_t hash_value(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    std::size_t seed = 0;
    for (const auto& val : vec) {
      boost::hash_combine(seed, val);
    }
    return seed;
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
stateSpaceLib.cpp:79:83: error: template argument 3 is invalid
 typedef std::unordered_map<std::vector<T>, State<T>*, boost::hash<std::vector<T>> Map;
                                                                                   ^
stateSpaceLib.cpp:79:1: error: template declaration of ‘typedef’
 typedef std::unordered_map<std::vector<T>, State<T>*, boost::hash<std::vector<T>> Map;
 ^
```

Comment: This sounds like exactly what `tuple` is for. But I don't understand what your final paragraph means.

Comment: @AlanStokes I've rewritten it, I hope it's a little better now.

Comment: Re: the syntax error - you need an extra '>': `boost::hash<std::vector<T>>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a vector - either on its own or wrap it in a struct with any other state data you need, and then if you have access to boost then use [hash_combine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html):

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::vector<int>, ObjectPointer, boost::hash<std::vector<int>> Map;

size_t hash_value(const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    std::size_t seed = 0;
    for (const auto& val : vec) {
      boost::hash_combine(seed, val);
    }
    return seed;
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible to parametrize the datatype? I mean something like `template <class T>`

Comment: @Eenoku: yes - just try it and ask specific questions if you have trouble.

Comment: Ok, what is the `ObjectPointer`? I have it as an undeclared symbol.

Comment: @TonyD I've added my first attempt into the description.

Answer (score 0):

The size is part of the type for `tuple`, so it wouldn't work.

But that's not the case for `vector`, so using that as the key should work just fine.

Unfortunately there is no standard overload for `std:hash` that accepts a `vector<int>`; you might be able to use boost to make up for this (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). Alternatively you can provide your own hash function.